# Architecture and interaction of the client, NestJS backend, and Python microservice

Tags: python, nestjs, microservices, message-queue, task-queue

As the title says, I have a question about the architecture and interaction of the client, NestJS backend, and Python microservice. I need to develop a recognition service. I have a client application that needs to send an HTTP request with an image to the NestJS backend, which should contact a third-party Python microservice, this service will recognize the text from the image (this can take a long time) and we should receive this response on the client application. What is the best way to implement this? I have an idea to connect NestJS with a Python microservice via RabbitMQ, the client sends a POST HTTP request to the NestJS backend, the backend sends a message to create a task via RPC to the Python microservice, which creates a Redis RQ queue with the task, returns the backend to the NestJS id of the task and starts to perform a long-running task, we return the task id to the client from the NestJS backend. After that, the client, with a certain interval, can send a GET HTTP request to the NestJS backend, which in turn will send a message to get the status of the task to the microservice and return the status to the client. [image: Here is a rough sketch of how I think it should work] Is this a good way to do it or is it possible to somehow optimize this process or implement it more competently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right track here.

1. Send image to nest via HTTP - yes
2. Post job to redis queue - yes, use nestjs builtin queue handling (see docs), this will make it easier to consume the product of the job as well
3. Instead of having your client poll for a result, check out [Server-sent Events](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/server-sent-events)

Server sent events are intended exactly for the use-case you are using.